# International Kapow! The Semi-Finalists

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, word-property

Simple Rules:
Each circle represents a category - which is as of yet unknown.
Each of the tiles below belongs to at least one of the categories.  Two have been placed for you - where do the others go and why?  Hopefully, this one is slightly harder than the last one - but I have been a poor judge so far!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to satisfy the title in full, the labels should be arranged like this:

> [image: Diagram with labels positiones]

Because the two ovals in this Venn diagram represent:

> *Left* - Words which appear at the **end of names of world countries**:
>  GER**MANY**, SW**EDEN**, CA**NADA** (or GRE**NADA**), S**PAIN**, HUN**GARY**, and DEN**MARK**.
>
>  *Right* - Words which appear as the last 4 letters of **first names of *[Take That](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_That)* members**:
>  J**ASON** Orange, HO**WARD** Donald, **GARY** Barlow, and **MARK** Owen.
>
>  GARY and MARK, therefore, both appear in the crossover section between the two ovals.

The logic behind this arrangement is fully suggested by the title, since:

> 'International' reflects the use of countries of the world, and 'Kapow!' is a Batman-esque equivalent of 'Take that!' Furthermore, 'semi' suggests words that are only partially complete, and 'finalists' implies the use of the *final* parts of words.

Comment: Sorry unsure how to spoiler on mobile.  You have one half right - the title can be used for more help.

Comment: @AlteringIntegral Aha, pretty sure I've got it now then! :)